# Insert php record from mysql table into a different table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've been searching for a long time for a solution to what I feel is a very simple problem.

I have a dynamically created page with a video that has a unique id. I also have a form that a user can submit content with. I want the id of the video to be included in the submission to tableA.

This code works great only when $id = 1.

```
$vidq = "SELECT * FROM tutorials";
$vidresult = mysql_query($vidq);
$vidrow = mysql_fetch_array($vidresult);

//form submission
if($_POST['formname'] == "submit") {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$id = $vidrow['id'];
$errorMessage = "";
if(empty($name)) {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>Please enter a valid name</li>";
    }

if(empty($errorMessage)) {

    $insert = "INSERT INTO tableA (videoid, name) VALUES (".$id.", ".$name.")"; 

    mysql_query($insert);
    exit();
    }
}
```

When I change $id to = 1, it posts, but when $id to = $vidrow['id'] it doesn't post.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Beware of [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/). And after that try `list($vidrow) = mysql_fetch_array(...)`

Comment: Don't you want to save the `id` of the video from the form? You are selecting a random row from the tutorials table and using its `id`. You should have the `id` of the video associated with the form in a hidden input in the form, then read that out of `$_POST` the same as the name. You also have a problem with the value of `$name` being neither escaped nor enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: @Linus Why would he want to do that? `mysql_fetch_array` returns a single row as an associative array, which is how he's trying to use it.

Comment: Is column with video ids in `tutorial` table named `id`? What errors did you get? more information on `it doesn\`t post`, please

Comment: Is your tutorials table empty?

Comment: Shouldn't `$name` in your query have single-quotes around? E.g. `'" . $name . "'`?

Comment: When you `echo $vidrow['id'];`, does it contain anything?

Comment: He does not need to select any rows from the table in the first place; these questions are missing the point.

Comment: @Dan `mysql_fetch_array()` has numeric indeces *and* column names in the result. It's unneeded overhead.

Comment: Maybe I did a bad job of describing the problem, but @Dan had the answer that worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try displaying the mysql error message by using mysql_errno/mysql_error. Eg...

```
if (!mysql_query($insert))
{
    die('MySQL Fail (' . mysql_errno() . ') - ' . mysql_error());
}
```

mysql_errno() documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php

Answer (score -2):

1. Have you tried to print out the contents of `$id` after `$id = $vidrow['id'];`? It might reveal why it doesn't work the way you want...
2. Have you thought about what might happen if a malicious (or just curious) user calls your script with `?name=%27%27%29%3b%20DROP%20TABLE%20tableA%3B`?

Comment: Yes. I thought it'd be easiest to add that code after I had the form submitting correctly. Thanks, though

Comment: That is a possible strategy, but it bears the risk that it is forgotten due to any reason (and be it because humans are like they are). Better do this stuff immediately - it is just a call to `mysql_real_escape()`. Just to mention.